# Bootstrap alert does not close

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to get a bootstrap alert to become dismissible, but I am unsure whether I need to add an onclick= event to my . I am referencing both Jquery and Bootstrap on my html page. Any ideas as to why the alert is not working?

```
<div class="alert alert-dismissible alert-info">
   <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
        <strong>Welcome to Version 1.0!</strong>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide us a JSFiddle.

Comment: a jsfiddle or the page url would be useful, thanks.

Comment: make sure you didnt forget bootstrap js <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

Comment: You shouldn't need to add a click event handler: http://bootply.com/91822 Make sure jQuery is before `bootstrap.js`

Comment: Hello, I am currently listing both Jquery and bootstrap which are in the following directories of my website:<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>